# How would I modify this code to shrink the pasted image by 50%

Tags: vba, image, copy, range, shrink

```
Sub Tester()
    Sheet1.Range("D5:E16").Copy
    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste Link:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

How can I shrink the image by a factor when pasting??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resize a picture you can use this:

```
Picture.ShapeRange.Width = 0.5 * Picture.Width
Picture.ShapeRange.Height = 0.75 * Picture.Height
```

A more in-depth example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584556/resize-and-change-the-format-of-multiple-pictures-using-excel-vba). I like to separate the pasting and resizing part, it keeps the code flexible.